# programmatically show on-screen keyboard in windows7 in .NET

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-7

Is there a way to programmatically open and show the Windows 7 on-screen keyboard using .NET? I've found two potential solutions but neither work. My app is WPF/.NET 4.

The first approach is from the two following links, but they require the on-screen keyboard to already be open as they use the FindWindow Win32 call:

http://hot-virtual-keyboard.com/development/q1/
[Finding the class name of the On-Screen Keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604033/finding-the-class-name-of-the-on-screen-keyboard)

The other route I've tried was this ([Show up the On Screen keyboard if the user sets the focus on a textfield. WPF with .Net 4 Client profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669854/show-up-the-on-screen-keyboard-if-the-user-sets-the-focus-on-a-textfield-wpf-wit)):

```
Process.Start("osk.exe");
```

But this call just fails with a message box that says "Could not start On-Screen Keyboard".

Any ideas?

Comment: `Process.Start("osk.exe")` works for me, wonder what's wrong there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What platform do you compile your application for? If it's set to `x86` that might cause that error if your system is 64 bit.

**Edit:** Just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929255/unable-to-launch-onscreen-keyboard-osk-exe-from-a-32-bit-process-on-win7-x64) which might be helpful if this is actually the cause.

Comment: Nice one, could repro it myself. Changed it to `Any CPU` and it worked just fine